# Ηow can I implement a clone of Digg?

Tags: php, mysql

Ι Decided to create my own clone of Digg and I wrote this little piece of code, which just display title and description.

```
<?php
try 
{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=informal','vad','6989');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = 'SELECT title,content FROM postID';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch())
{
    echo $row['title'] . "<br />";
    echo $row['content'] . "<br />";
}
?>
```

And I would like, that title to be a link, and when user click on that link, database could define this record and show this article in the new page. True the fact, I did it with `input type = hidden`, that when you click to button "open" and it shows all. I need a more flexible approach, just like in Digg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass parameter between two pages So first of all your have to edit add link on it

```
<?php
try 
{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=informal','vad','6989');
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = 'SELECT title,content FROM postID';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch())
{
    echo "<a href=anotherpage.php?id=".$row['id'].">".$row['title'] . "</a><br />";
    echo $row['content'] . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Then on the other page you have to query with your passed ID .. And then you have to fetch data with it